# Hybris Impex import based on PKs obtained from FlexQuery

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to set the value of two attributes, a1 and a2, to null for any product where a third attribute, a3, has a specific enum value.

**What I have so far:**

I have a flexquery which fetches a list of PKs for products which fulfill the requirement for a3. I now need to set the attributes of the products with those specific keys. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT {p.pk} FROM {Product AS p JOIN ProductOrigin AS o ON {o.pk} = {p.origin}} WHERE {o.code} = 'MARKETPLACE'
```

**What I need help with:**

I do not know how to combine the results of the flexquery with a typical impex operation. What I ideally want is to be able to simply pass the list of PKs to an INSERT_UPDATE as in:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product; pk         ; a1  ; a2  ;
                       queryResult; null; null;
```

I do not know if this is possible however. Even better would be if there is an even easier way to do this that I have not thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Erik you can achieve this even without using the Impex header and use groovy, steps are below.

1. Create groovy

   #%impex.enableCodeExecution(true);

   "#%groovy%

   ```
    def queryCreditCardsToRemove = ''' SELECT {p.pk} FROM {Product AS p JOIN ProductOrigin AS o ON {o.pk} = {p.origin}} WHERE {o.code} = 'MARKETPLACE''''

    def products = (Collection<ProductModel>)flexibleSearchService.search(queryCreditCardsToRemove).result
    products.stream()
             .each{
             modelService
             }
    modelService.removeAll(cardsToRemove)
   ```

   ";
2. Save the file as impex

3.# Disable legacy scripting (makes groovy work at impex)
impex.legacy.scripting=false---> either you can change dynamically via hac-->configuration or add in local.properties

Answer (score 0):

here is one **beanshell** script, execute it from **hac -> console -> scripting languages!**

In the below script, you need to put query that will give you result which is expected to you and on that result script will do further operations of saving null values to attributes!

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel
import de.hybris.platform.variants.model.VariantProductModel;

final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String query = "-------------- query to check condition of third (a3) attribute 
                          with specific enum value ----------------------"
params = -----------if any need to be passed in query ------------------;

FlexibleSearchService fss = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")
final SearchResult<ProductModel> searchResult = fss.search(query, params);

for (final ProductModel product : searchResult.getResult()) {
    // set attributes a1 and a2 to null 
    // save product model using modelService
}
```